# Prove: $A\times B=\emptyset \leftrightarrow A=\emptyset \vee B=\emptyset$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, proof-verification

First of all I wanna say that I'm not too convinced about this proof since I found it too simplistic, but please take a look at it and let me know what I should improve.

$P \to Q$

By hypothesis $A\times B=\emptyset$ then for any pair $(x,y), (x,y) \notin A\times B$. Therefore $x\notin A$ or $y\notin B$ by Cartesian product definition (?). Then $A=\emptyset$ or $B=\emptyset$.

$Q \to P$

By hypothesis $A= \emptyset$ or $B= \emptyset$ then $x\notin A$ or $y\notin B$ for any $x,y$. By definition of Cartesian product we have that $(x,y) \notin A\times B$ for any pair $(x,y)$. So, $A\times B=\emptyset$.

Any good?

Answer (score 1):

In your proof of $P \rightarrow Q$, you've almost gotten there - but the leap from "$x \notin A$ or $y \notin B$" to "either $A$ or $B$ is empty" is far from clear. In principle, it could be that some $x$'s are in $A$, and some $y$'s are in $B$, but they just never "happen" at the same time. The way I'd prove this is by contrapositive - suppose that $A$ and $B$ are both nonempty. Then there exists some $x \in A$ and some $y \in B$. What can be said about the pair $(x,y)$?

Your other half is fine, though.

Comment: In your proof I can say that $(x,y) \notin A\times B$ wich contradicts the hypotesis. Correct?

Comment: @Mr.Lu Well, the way I wrote it there is no hypothesis (the proof shows that if $A$ and $B$ are nonempty then $A \times B$ is not empty) but yes, you have the right idea.

Answer (score 0):

My 2 cents: prove the equivalent by contrapositive:

$$A\times B\ne \emptyset\iff A\ne \emptyset \land B\ne \emptyset$$

Answer (score 0):

Yes the proof you show is valid, however like you are working with sets I recommend using the $\subseteq$ rather than $\rightarrow$